# How to install a package from within my application?

Tags: application-development, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install a ‘recommended’ package when user asks for corresponding action](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174725/install-a-recommended-package-when-user-asks-for-corresponding-action)

I am a developer and for my application i require some packages to be installed.
So when for example the user tries to activate a feature of the programm (that requires a package ), i want to popup a messagebox asking that he needs that package in order to activate the feature..

Yes install "package name" / Cancel

So when he hits yes popup this dialog and install the packages:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to do that? A certain command or something?

Comment: So you don't want your program to download all its dependencies at install time, only when the user reaches certain feature?

Comment: You can download synaptic source code to see how it is implemented in synaptic

Comment: @ThiagoPonte Yep exactly, when he activates a certain feature. My way of doing this until now, was to direct the user to the Ubuntu's software center page and from there he installed it. But it's kinda ugly that way...

Comment: @Tachyons and in which cc file will i see how it is implemented in synaptic? I downloaded the source, but in the common folder there are about 15 cc files..